# is google chrome underline style changed?

Tags: google-chrome, hover, underline

[image: Google chrome underline style]

I started noticing the anchor tags underline style change for letters like "p" "g", "j" "y" is this recently changed or I started noticing late. Anyone feels same ?

Comment: [Cross site dupe](https://superuser.com/questions/1293529/when-did-chrome-start-underlining-links-differently) and was a better fit for there...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I have noticed the same style change within the last few days,

Yes google have changed their link styles recently, seen this from another post

*In Chrome 57 we shipped support for text-decoration-skip: ink; which allows skipping descenders in underlines (illustration). We initially suggested making it the default in the intent process but dropped this part for shipping because we had assumed a spec change was required.
We would now like to enable ink skipping by default.*

https://superuser.com/questions/1293529/when-did-chrome-start-underlining-links-differently

Answer (score 3):

Short answer: yes.

It is a horrible design idea. This new underline styling of Chrome is even "adding" visual elements, example: [Smitty](https://www.stackoverflow.com) ← mouseover the link, then you see a point after the last letter. Horrible design idea of Chrome this time. Screenshot:

[image: chrome underline point]

You can install this Chrome extension by inkSkip: https://superuser.com/a/1294080/169199 to get back the old style.